# Make div bigger then its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there any way how can I make div bigger then its parent? I know its bad practice.
Basically I have div that is small and I need to create div inside which will be through entire window. But cant find way how to do it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Parent div must be `position: relative;` and child: `position: absolute;`. In this case is possible to make any size of child div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "pop" that element from normal flow with `position` rule with specified dimensions. E.g. `position: fixed;`

```css
.outer {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vh;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(130, 130, 255, .3);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  background: rgba(130, 255, 130, .3);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Alternative**

Have `overflow: visible` with specified dimensions

```css
.outer {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vh;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(130, 130, 255, .3);
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.inner {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgba(130, 255, 130, .3);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one looks great but i cant work with px. Childs needs to be through entire window/screen.

Comment: @JGeorgeJ So use `vw` units instead then

Comment: @JGeorgeJ I have updated from `px` to `vw`/`vh`

Comment: yeah position fixed and 100% do the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily. As long as the parent doesn't have `overflow: hidden`, you can even define its dimensions with pixels and see it working!

```css
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

If you want it over the entire screen, you can use `vh` and `vw`:

```
.child {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use absolute sizing in CSS to have a child `div` be larger than the parent. You will also need to add in the `top` and `left` attributes and set them to 0. This will frame the `div` to begin in the top left corner.

If you want a `div` to be the full width and height of the viewport, use the following CSS:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will allow the `div` to resize based on the user's screen dimensions.

More on CSS sizing can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS).

Comment: Its not working but thanks for try.

Comment: Updated to show it working successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Give a certain `height` & `width` to your parent. 
Use `%` for the your `.child` element.

```css
.parent {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.child {
  height: 125%;
  width: 125%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```